# github actions workflow call if statement with custom env vars

Tags: if-statement, github-actions, workflow

If I have set a custom env var like so:

```
env:
  web_app_1: none
```

and then I want to run a workflow based off of an if expression:

```
  build_artifact:
      uses: ./.github/workflows/X-Call-build-artifact.yml
      if: web_app_1 != 'none'
      secrets: inherit
      with:
        artifact-name:  $web_app_1 #put in the functions or web app names you want to publish
        path: $web_app_1_artifact_path # and path to it
```

it return the error:
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/Dev-Pipeline.yml (Line: 37, Col: 11): Unrecognized named-value: 'web_app_1'. Located at position 1 within expression: web_app_1 != 'none'

I tried using ${{ web_app_1 }}, ${{ enn.web_app_1 }}, and $web_app_1

all giving similar errors...

if there not a way to call a workflow with an if conditional?

Comment: What about `if: env.web_app_1 != 'none'`?

Comment: looks like that doesnt work either :/ 
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/Dev-Pipeline.yml (Line: 38, Col: 11): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.web_app_1 != 'none'

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around I figured out. Should be a more elegant solution but it works...

```
env:
  web_app_1: none
  web_app_1_artifact_path: 'Code/location/'
  function_1: none
  function_1_artifact_path: 'Code/location/' 


jobs:

  check_resources:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      has_web_app: ${{ steps.web.outputs.declared }}
      has_function: ${{ steps.function.outputs.declared }}
    steps:
      - name: Check web app
        id: web
        if: ${{ env.web_app_1 != 'none' }}
        run: echo "::set-output name=declared::true"
      - name: Check functions
        id: function
        if: ${{ env.function_1 != 'none' }}
        run: echo "::set-output name=declared::true"

  build_artifact:
      uses: ./.github/workflows/X-Call-build-artifact.yml
      needs: [check_resources]
      if: ${{ (needs.check_resources.outputs.has_web_app == 'true') && (needs.check_resources.outputs.has_function == 'true')}}
      secrets: inherit
      with:
        artifact-name:  $web_app_1 #put in the functions or web app names you want to publish
        path: $web_app_1_artifact_path # and path to it
```

essentially adds a job to make the if statement on the set env var then sets the output values, then the workflow call job uses the output on the if.